# Rails: create database structure for an archive

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I have a general architectural question concerning the design of part of a database. I would like to implement an archive for an educational entity and have a form field, where I can query the archive and get a certain subset of entries. Everything started with only an archive of articles and lectures. I treated both as similar and used one table named `resources` with columns for all the data I needed in both cases. This way I could write in my Rails app something like:

```
Resources.find(:all).where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:searchTitle]}%")
```

and get all the resources with a certain string in its title.

Now I would like to extend the archive to comprehend a wider set of resources containing documentation of educational or research activities. I will have **items** as well as what you could call **collections** and **sub collections**. Items would be things like sheets, texts, images, magazines, books, music, video, drawings, models, maps. Collections would be something like courses, lectures, exercises, projects, exhibitions. A course can have multiple exercises and lectures. An exercise can have multiple projects, etc. But there might be projects without an exercise or course. I might choose to add keywords to the resources to describe content.

A query should result in a view with all related entries of single items and collections in one list.

I would usually create a table for each resource in order to have as few repeating data as possible. But I usually have one table as entry point for my queries and would have now 14 resources tables + join tables + tables such as authors. How should I set up the structure of such a database and in case I will have to create single tables for each resource: How do I query 14 tables and display the result in one list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, do you want to search in one query ? or you want to get the search result in one array?

Comment: I do not know. I would like to build something like an Online public access catalog and be able to search for title, author, keyword, description. Performance wise I should probably make as few queries as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller action method,

```
resources1 = Resource1.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchTitle]}%")
resources2 = Resource2.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchTitle]}%")
resources3 = Resource3.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchTitle]}%")
@total_results = resources1 + resources2 + resources3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way I am able to search multiple resources. Now I only need to find out how to paginate total_results.